# Finding the equation of the plane which consists two lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem:

> Given $$L_1: x= -1+4t, y=3+t, z=1$$ $$L_2:x=-13+12t, y=1+6t, z=2+3t$$ Find the plane which consists $L_1$ and $L_2$.

So I found that $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect at $(-17, -1, 1)$. But what now?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a very similar problem and how to determine the plane: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071028224751AA98eZG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $L_1$ in the form $\underline x = \underline a + t \underline u$ and $L_2$ in the form $\underline x = \underline b + t \underline v$.

Denoting by $\underline z$ the point of intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$, your plane is given by
$$
\underline x = \underline z + t\underline u + s\underline v.
$$

Comment: what is $s$?,any constant right?

Comment: $s$ and $t$ are real numbers that parametrize the plane,i.e. each combination $(s,t)$ gives you a point of the plane, and every point of the plane corresponds to one combination $(s,t)$.